# How to sort a vector according to a given sequence in R

Tags: r, sorting, random

I'm trying to organize a sequence of data according to a given sequence. For example, the given sequence I have is

```
set.seed(1)
given_seq <- sample(rep(1:3,2))
```

The data and its associated sequence

```
dat_seq <- rep(1:3,2)
dat_value <- rnorm(6)
```

And I want to organize the data according to the given sequence. That is, 1,2,3 serve as a function of labels of data. For example,

```
dat_value
[1]  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.4874291  0.7383247  0.5757814

dat_seq
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3

given_seq
[1] 2 3 3 1 1 2
```

Then I expect the second and fifth data values (with label 2) are placed at first or sixth places.

I can see that the organized sequence is not unique, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: what would be the expected outcome for the new order of `dat_value`?

Comment: @Nate I just edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: This seems really weird with non-unique labels. If your labels are unique, you could easily use the `names` attribute, but without unique labels you may have to build your own method. When you "expect the second and fifth data values (with label 2) are placed at first or sixth places", do you expect the 2nd and 5th must correspond with 1st and 6th? Or is it okay to be 6th and 1st? Is it okay if the 2nd is repeated at both 1st and 6th the 5th is missing?

Comment: @Gregor Yes I agree this is a bit weird. Maybe I should not have used the term label for this problem. And yes it is okay to be 6th and 1st, but either one cannot be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
dat_value[match(rank(given_seq, ties = "random"), rank(dat_seq, ties = "random"))]
# [1]  0.7383247  0.5757814 -0.8204684  1.5952808  0.4874291  0.3295078
```

First we convert the two sequences into ones that have no repetitive elements; e.g.,

```
rank(given_seq, ties = "random")
# [1] 3 5 6 1 2 4
```

That is, if two entries of `given_seq` are, say, (1,1), then they will randomly be converted into (1,2) or (2,1). The same is done with `dat_seq` and, consequently, we can match them and reorder `dat_value` accordingly. Thus, this kind of method would give you some randomization, which may or may not be something desirable in your application.

Comment: This allows for randomization and is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would just make the labels unique and use the `names` attribute normally.

```
names(dat_value) = make.unique(as.character(dat_seq))
dat_value[make.unique(as.character(given_seq))]
 #         2          3        3.1          1        1.1        2.1 
 # 0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.5757814  1.5952808  0.4874291  0.7383247
```

You can always strip the names off later if the non-uniqueness doesn't work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This also works, probably even faster, although it may be harder to understand

```
dat_value[order(dat_seq)][order(order(given_seq))]
```

First, we re-order dat_value so that it's corresponding to the sequence `c(1,1,2,2,3,3)`.

Then we go for the desired order, which would be `given_seq` if that was sequential. Fortunately, twice calling order just makes it sequential.

Comment: `order(order(given_seq))` is really clever!